# Unity - Panel is disabled and re-enabled immediately afterwards (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Just need a way to get around this problem. I know what the issue is, I just need a viable solution.

So basically I have a script called MouseManager, which detects if you're looking at a specific game object and if you press "f" it tells another script, called UIManager, to open the GameObject's panel (I have a game where you can press f on a console and it enables a UI with a puzzle).

Basically, I want the user to be able to press "f" or "esc" and have it exit the panel, however if you press "f", it disables the panel but instantly re-enables it as you're still looking at the gameobject, and both checks are in Update()

I need a workaround, if anyone knows one PLEASE comment as this issue is getting on my nerves :P

Thanks

EDIT: By console I mean there's a GameObject that looks like a console.

EDIT 2: Here's the code, I'll put some comments in it so you can understand what each thing does. I will be refactoring it soon because it's messy...

```
void Start()
{
    uiPuzzles = GameObject.Find("PuzzlesUI").GetComponentInChildren<UIManager>(); // Currently I have the UIManager set to a canvas called PuzzlesUI. I will soon be moving it to an empty GameObject.
}

void Update()
{
    if (!uiPuzzles.invActive && !uiPuzzles.puzzleActive) // invActive and puzzleActive are two public booleans that just show if the inventory or any puzzle panel is empty (UIManager handles opening and closing the inventory too)
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Use") && !uiPuzzles.invActive && !uiPuzzles.puzzleActive) // Use key is bound to "f". Currently Im just checking if puzzleActive and invActive are still false.
        {
            ray = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>().ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 7)) // Raycast where you're looking
            {
                uiPuzzles.openPuzzleOverlay(hit.collider.name); // function in UIManager which will check if the hit collider is in a list of all the puzzle colliders currently added and if it is, open that panel.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for UIManager:

```
public void openPuzzleOverlay(string collider) // Get a panel name
{
    foreach (Puzzle item in puzzleList)
    {
        item.panelGameObject.SetActive(false); // Disable all puzzle panels.
        if (item.consoleGameObject.name == collider) // unless its the given panel,
        {
            item.panelGameObject.SetActive(true); // then enable it.
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None; // Unlock the mouse.
            Cursor.visible = true; // Show the mouse.
            DisablePlayerUI(); // Disable the UI (e.g. crosshair)
            puzzleActive = true; // Disable movement. (Because player movement requires puzzleActive and invActive to also be false
        }
    }
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Use") && puzzleActive && !invActive && // If you want to use a console and the puzzle is already active
        !puzzleList.Where(p => p.panelGameObject.activeSelf).FirstOrDefault().panelGameObject.GetComponentInChildren<InputField>().isFocused) // Check if the currently active panel's input field is not focused.
    {
        ClosePuzzleOverlay(); // Close the puzzle.
        EnablePlayerUI(); // Enable the UI.
    }

}

public void ClosePuzzleOverlay()
{
    foreach (Puzzle item in puzzleList)
        item.panelGameObject.SetActive(false);
    Cursor.visible = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    puzzleActive = false;
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: done. Sorry it took so long, had to add some clarification comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is being caused by the two input checks. When F is pressed both are true so the UI is being closed and then opened in the same frame.

Take the Input code out of UIManager and keep it in one place.  Then you can rework your input class to be something like this:

```
//MouseManager Update 
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Use")){
     if(uiPuzzles.isActive)
         uiPuzzles.Hide();
    else
        uiPuzzles.Show(GetPuzzleName());
}
```

Now it will only call either open or close on the frame which F is pressed down.